# How to upsert values in Postgres catching exceptions while identifying modifications to a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert

I have two tables in Postgres, `t_product` and `t_product_modifications` having the following respective structures:

**t_product**

```
product_code    product_category     owner
============    ================     =====
  A                home               Jack
  B                office             Daniel
  C                outdoor            Jack
  D                home               Susan

(the 'product_code' and 'product_category' are unique together and is a composite primary key. 
There is also a NOT NULL constraint on the 'owner' column)
```

**t_product_modifications**

```
product_code       last_modified_time
============       ==================
 A                 2020-04-07 16:10:30
 B                 2020-04-07 16:10:30
 C                 2020-04-07 16:10:30
 D                 2020-04-07 16:10:30
```

I basically need to do a bulk insert/update into the `t_product` table. And only if there has been a modification to a record, i should update the `last_modified_time` column in the `t_product_modifications` table. In addition to this, it is important that the entire bulk upsert should not fail if some other constraints have failed for certain records but rather it should just return a list of product_codes or an error log for which the upserts were not possible. (Also, for certain reasons I can't have both tables as one)

For example, let us say i am trying to do a bulk upsert for the following values into the `t_product` table:

```
1. ('A','home', 'Susan')
2. ('B','office', 'Daniel')
3. ('E','office', NULL)
4. ('F','home', NULL)
```

When trying to insert the above four values, this is what needs to happen

1. The first record should be updated successfully for `('A','home')` primary key and the value `Susan` should be updated in the `owner` column. Since this record was an update to the `t_product` table, the `last_modified_time` for the respective product should be updated in the `t_product_modifications` table.
2. Ignore the second record. Basically it should not make any changes to the `t_product_modifications` table since there are no modifications being made to the `t_product` table
3. The third record should be a part of the output error log or exception since the owner field cannot be `NULL`
4. the fourth record should be a part of the output error log or exception since the owner field cannot be `NULL`

I will be executing this Postgres query from a Python script and wish to save all errors that happened during upsert without the entire query failing. I was unable to find a solution on StackOverflow that was efficient enough.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am a bit confused why you removed 'database' from the list of tags. This is a database operation after all right?

Comment: Yes, and PostgreSQL **is** a database, so it's kind ob unnecessary

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Oh I thought if ppl wanted to filter question by the respective tag, it would help to have 'database' in it for their reference

Answer (score 0):

[Trigger procedures](https://postgrespro.com/docs/postgresql/9.6/plpgsql-trigger) are perfect for solving your problem. You need to create a procedure that will be executed when a record of the `t_product` table is updated and check if the values ​​of the columns have changed, if true, then update the `last_modified_time` column from the `t_product_modifications` table.

Your Trigger:

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_product() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
  BEGIN
    IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') AND OLD!=NEW THEN
       UPDATE t_product_modifications SET last_modified_time = NOW() WHERE product_code = New.product_code;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW; 
  END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
  
CREATE TRIGGER update_product_modified_time BEFORE UPDATE ON t_product FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_product();
```

Demo in [DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6560546f1fcb3749b324fa1bb8d9ef4b)

---

```
 -- This will update the last_modified_time in the t_product_modifications table
    UPDATE t_product SET product_category = 'home', owner = 'Susan'  WHERE product_code = 'A'; 

 -- Nothing will happen
    UPDATE t_product SET product_category = 'office', owner = 'Daniel' WHERE product_code = 'B';
```